# How can I check the version of BIND on Debian

Tags: debian, ssh, networking, bind

I am using Debian and when I give the command `sudo named -v` it returns command not found.

I want to verify that my ssh server (sshd) is using bind version 9.1.3 or later so that it both is IPv6 capable and secure.

How can I do this?

Comment: are your "ssh server" and your "bind server" and your "Debian server" the same? different?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask *dpkg* for the packages's version.

```
dpkg -l bind9
```

Or directly to BIND's binary.

```
sudo named -v
```

Comment: Did you read the text in my question?

Comment: So I have to agree with @stephen-kitt and tell you BIND isn't installed at all. Your SSH server must query another server, which is the actual DNS server.

Comment: I have the option UseDNS set to "no".

Comment: That only means your authentication and logging aren't making DNS queries. But your whole system is. Notice that be able to translate a name into IP doesn't mean to run a DNS server. Check your /etc/resolve.conf and you'll see your DNS server.

Comment: root privs are not needed.  Just `named -v` will do.  or `/usr/sbin/named -v` if `/usr/sbin` is not in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Not reliable, on account of folks not using bind or not responding to the version query, but might be handy if one lacks local access to a DNS server. Specify a hostname or IP address as first argument.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec dig +short -c chaos -t txt @"$1" version.bind
```

Comment: or `awk '/^nameserver/ {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf | xargs -I{} dig +short -c chaos -t txt @"{}" version.bind`